# RPM package contents in Fedora running under WSL2

Tags: fedora, windows, rpm

I'm confused. I have a Fedora 36 "machine" running under WSL2 on windows box. And either there's some heavy magic that I don't know of going on or I simply don't understand something. Let's take bash as an example:.

```
# ls -la /usr/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1390064 Jan 19  2022 /usr/bin/bash
# rpm -qf /usr/bin/bash
bash-5.1.16-2.fc36.x86_64
# rpm -ql bash | grep bash.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
# stat /usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
stat: cannot statx '/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz': No such file or directory
# rpm -V bash
#
```

What gives? There are no files in /usr/share/man/man1 or /usr/share/locale from the package yet the rpm doesn't show any errors on verify. If I do a dnf install, there are no new files showing up in /usr/share/doc or /usr/share/man...
Yet if I manually touch /usr/share/doc/test file, it shows up and stays in the directory.
I suspect it might have something to do with RPM configuration but I have no idea where to look for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dnf` is configured with `tsflags=nodocs`, in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`; this means that it installs RPMs with [the `--excludedocs` flag](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-install-additional-options.html), so that documentation (including man pages) isn’t installed.

`rpm` still considers the non-installed files to be part of the package, which is why `rpm -ql` lists the files even though they aren’t present on disk.